# Is there a issue with <apex:selectCheckboxes> when associated to apex properties?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am defining a apex property `public String[] values{get; set;}` and calling it in VF page

```
`<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!values}">`
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

But when I submit the selected values using  <`apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!submit}" rerender="out" status="status"/>` submit function in apex code is  not called. Interestingly the same stuff works when I define individual get and set method for ‘values’ … something like …

```
public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
```

Also another interesting thing what I noticed was it works fine with `<apex:selectList/>`

```
<apex:selectList value="{!values}" multiSelect="true" size="4">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
```

Is this a bug anybody aware off ?

If needed I shall post the entire code.

Comment: I faced the same problem

Comment: I think this is a bug of a sort - looking through some of my code, I see I've used individual getters and setters as well. I can't remember having the issue, but I probably did.

Comment: why aren't you declaring it as a list of Boolean: `public Boolean[] values {get; set;}` ? and I assume those reverse quotes in your code block are a copy-paste error

Comment: Did you try as suggested by @crop1645?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this getter setters in two ways one is your correct but the other one you have to intialize it in the constructor

```
public class xyz {

  public String[] values{get; set;}
  // my method of using getters and setters
  public WrapperAccountController(){
   values=new String[]{'a','b'};

  }
  //Your Method
  public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you solve the problem.